# Primefaces Datatable autoComplete and focus

Tags: primefaces, datatable, autocomplete, focus, jsf-2.2

first I'd like to thank you guys for all the work you've done here on SO. I really appreciate that.

Here's my problem:

Currently I'm working on a project that is using **JavaEE** 7. We are using **PrimeFaces** version 5.3 as GUI-Toolkit.
One part of the GUI is a `p:dataTable` where some entries are editable in `"cell"` mode. Others are not editable but are calculated using the editable cells.
Also most of the editable cells use `p:autoComplete` as input facet.

A user now should be able to use different interaction styles like *tabbing* through the cells, *clicking* with the mouse or hitting *enter* on a cell.
In all of these interactions the values that need to be recalculated should be updated as well as some other widgets.

The code I am referring to is also available here:
https://github.com/HerrDesSchwachsinns/SO-Table
The test project uses Glassfish Server 4, the initial code is
[WebContent/table-v1.xhtml].

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Table</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table.css" />
    <h:link value="index" outcome="index" />
    <h:form id="formId">
        <p:remoteCommand name="onCellEdit"
            update=":#{p:component('valueTableId')}" />
        <p:dataTable id="valueTableId" var="values" value="#{bean.values}"
            editable="true" editMode="cell" tabindex="100">
            <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{bean.onCellEdit}"
                oncomplete="onCellEdit()"
                update="@this, :#{p:component('valueTableId')}" />
            <p:column headerText="x" id="xCellId">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{values.x}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{values.x}">
                            <p:ajax event="change"
                                update="@this, :#{p:component('valueTableId')}"
                                oncomplete="onCellEdit()" />
                        </p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="y" id="yCellId">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{values.y}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{values.y}">
                            <p:ajax event="change"
                                update="@this, :#{p:component('valueTableId')}"
                                oncomplete="onCellEdit()" />
                        </p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Calc" id="calcCellId" styleClass="gray">
                <h:outputText value="#{values.calc}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

`bean.onCellEdit` calculates the new calc values

---

Using enter to commit a value works fine as does a mouse click outside the widget. But if one clicks inside the widget strange things happen.
First the value does not get updated. Clicking again on a cell inside the widget triggers the calculation again but does not focus the cell. more precisely, it does but then it blurs again. Using tab key yields the same behavior. Only after one clicks outside the widget the behavior is normal again.

In version 2 [table-v2.xhtml] I managed to get tabbing and clicking right but I had to sacrifice the enter-press.

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Table</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table.css" />
    <h:link value="index" outcome="index" />
    <h:form id="formId">
        <p:dataTable id="valueTableId" var="values"
            value="#{bean.values}" editable="true" editMode="cell">
            <p:column headerText="x" id="xCellId">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{values.x}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{values.x}">
                            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.onCellEdit}"
                                update="calcCellOutputId" />
                        </p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="y" id="yCellId">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{values.y}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{values.y}">
                            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.onCellEdit}"
                                update="calcCellOutputId" />
                        </p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Calc" id="calcCellId" styleClass="gray">
                <h:outputText value="#{values.calc}" id="calcCellOutputId" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

But this version did use `p:inputText` instead of `p:autoComplete`.
In version [table-v3.xhtml] and [table-v4.xhtml] they are inserted (v3 is derived from v1, v4 from v2).
With those in play not even tabbing works correctly anymore.

```xml
....
<f:facet name="input">
    <p:autoComplete value="#{values.x}"
        completeMethod="#{bean.completeX}" dropdown="true"
        forceSelection="true">
        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.onCellEdit}"
            update="@this calcCellOutputId" />
    </p:autoComplete>
</f:facet>
....
```

I'm new to *Java Server Faces/PrimeFaces* so I might have missed something.
But I did work for nearly one week (intermittently) on this problem and can't figure out how to solve it.
I cannot change the overall layout decision meaning cell editing is mandatory.
Also this seems to be an `update` problem.

I hope I was sufficiently precise.
Oh and I forgot: Many thanks in advance.

---

[stripped down version of the dataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuyAh.png)

Comment: please post code here and not somewhere else... Having code in external projects is not in line with StackOverflow 'guidelines'

Comment: good to know, thank you